# Why the div is not being clone and copyied to new div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a `div` and append it to another div. But why is the clone not working in this code?

```
<form>
  <div id="newAutomaticItemDiv" class="col s10 hidden" hidden="hidden">
    <article class="row" id="invoiceLineItem">
      <label>Select GL Account</label>
      <select class="combobox padding-top-2x" name="GeneralLedgerAccount.LookupTypeId" data-val-lookup_required="GL Account field is required for Auto Generated invoice setup.">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">text 1</option>
        <option value="2">3</option>
      </select>


      <input type="text" />
    </article>
  </div>

  <div id="AutomaticInvoiceItemList">

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" onclick="addAutomaticInvoiceLineItem()">
      <span>Add GL</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to clone from `newAutomaticItemDiv` to `AutomaticInvoiceItemList`.

Jquery:

```
function addAutomaticInvoiceLineItem() {
  debugger;
  var autoInvoiceIndex = 0;
  var autogeneratedInvoicesContainer = $("#AutomaticInvoiceItemList" + autoInvoiceIndex);
  var newAutomaticItemDiv = $("#newAutomaticItemDiv");

  // Clone the empty Add New row and add it to the Automatic Invoices container
  var cloneAutomaticDiv = newAutomaticItemDiv.clone();
  autogeneratedInvoicesContainer.append(cloneAutomaticDiv.children()[0]);

}
```

Js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k0prs7jw/

Comment: `#AutomaticInvoiceItemList + 0` does not exists?

Comment: It doesn't create?

Comment: $ is a selector

Comment: You can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xasL6q0g/) .

Comment: Note, if your sole purpose of some HTML is for it to be cloned, then consider using `<template>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this logic is going well.
The purpose is to copy the `newAutomaticItemDiv` to `AutomaticInvoiceItemList`.
But You wrote the code like this.

```
var autoInvoiceIndex = 0;
var autogeneratedInvoicesContainer = $("#AutomaticInvoiceItemList" + autoInvoiceIndex);
// refer one which id is AutomaticInvoiceItemList0
```

But this is not located in your html code.

```
<div id="AutomaticInvoiceItemList">
    
</div>
```

Please update mentioned part.

Comment: So you're saying, instead of `$("#AutomaticInvoiceItemList" + autoInvoiceIndex);` OP should have used `$("#AutomaticInvoiceItemList");`

Comment: Please replace with it.
 <div id="AutomaticInvoiceItemList0">

  </div>

and then Please click the button to check